# finding rows which don't have NA in a particular column if it already didn't have any NA

Tags: r, rstudio

I just observed that if one of the columns in my data frame does not contain any NA values(see col2 below) and I unknowingly, try to find rows which do not have the corresponding col2 value as NA, the below code gives me an empty output.

See col1 below where it works since, it has at least one NA value.
The same does not work for col2

```
> col1 = c(1,1,1,1,NA)
> col2 = c(2,2,2,2,2)
> df = data.frame(col1,col2)
> df
  col1 col2
1    1    2
2    1    2
3    1    2
4    1    2
5   NA    2
> df[-which(is.na(df$col1)),]
  col1 col2
1    1    2
2    1    2
3    1    2
4    1    2
> df[-which(is.na(df$col2)),]
[1] col1 col2
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I was able to get it to work as follows, but just wondering if the above behavior is okay?

```
> df[which(! is.na(df$col2)),]
  col1 col2
1    1    2
2    1    2
3    1    2
4    1    2
5   NA    2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not limited to NAs. It happens if the indexing vector is empty. The *hope* is that the whole vector will be returned, but actually, `x[numeric(0)]` (`x` indexed by a vector of length `0`) returns an empty vector.

For example, consider the following:

```
> df[ c(-1), ] # Negative indexing
  col1 col2
2    1    2
3    1    2
4    1    2
5   NA    2
> df[ c(), ] # numeric(0)
[1] col1 col2
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> df[ c(1), ] # Positive indexing
  col1 col2
1    1    2
```

See section 8.1.13 in the [R inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) for a more general explanation and work arounds.